# Select2 version 4.0 allowClear strange behavior

Tags: jquery-select2

The new version of Select2 4.0 by specifying allowClear: true, put's an 'x' on the select box. Clicking on it removes the selected entry and also opens up the box. This is a new behavior. In the previous version the box didn't open when 'x' was clicked. Is there a way to turn off this behavior?

Comment: [This is a known change in Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3320) and there is currently no built-in way to work around it.

Comment: @KevinBrown quick question. Is there ability to use a function that returns a promise. Let's say I had a client side service that handled ajax for me. It gets the data from the remote source then caches it locally. How can I implement this with Select2 4.0.